# Flutter 3.10.5 can't run in iOs simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Can't run on iOS simulator, after updating flutter to latest version `3.10.5`. Please see the logs below.

> Error (Xcode):
> /Applications/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:12:8:
> Error: Error when reading
> '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.6.0/lib/expect.dart':
> No such file or directory
>
> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode... Running
> Xcode build... Xcode build done.
> 11.0s Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): /Applications/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:12:8:
> Error: Error when reading
> '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/test_api-0.6.0/lib/expect.dart':
> No such file or directory
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 14 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some files are not available at test_api-0.6.0.

I have done a workaround.

```
dependency_overrides:
  test_api: 0.5.2
```